# Can Couchbase 2.0 be accessed from erlang via erlmc & memchache 1.3 protocol?

Tags: erlang, memcached, couchbase

I'm developing an application in erlang/elixir.  I'd like to access Couchbase 2.0 from erlang.  I found the erlmc project (https://github.com/JacobVorreuter/erlmc ) which is a binary protocol memcached client.  The notes say "you must have a version 1.3 or greater of memcached."

I understand that Couchbase 2.0 uses memcached binary protocol for accessing data, and I'm looking for the best way to do this from erlang.

The manual talks about a "Couchbase API Port" on 8092, and calls the 11210 (close to the 11211 memcached normal port) as "internal cluster port".
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-network-ports.html

So, the question is this:

Is setting up erlmc to talk to Couchbase 2.0 on port 8092 the correct way to go about it?

Erlmc talks about how it hashes keys to find the right server, which makes me think that it might be too old of a version of the memcached protocol (or is there a built in MOXI on couchbase 2.0 that I should be connecting to?  If so which port?)

Which is the port for the erlang views?  And presumably the REST interface for views does not support straight key lookups, so I'll need to write code to access that as well, right?

I'm keen to use a pure erlang solution since NIFs are not concurrent and I'll have some unknown number of processes wanting to access Couchbase 2.0 at the same time.

The last time I worked with Couch was CouchDB, and so I'm trying to piece things together after the merger of Couch and Membase.

If I'm off on the wrong track, please advise on the best way to access Couchbase 2.0 from erlang in a highly concurrant manner.  The memcached protocol should be pretty solid, thus possibly libraries a couple years old should work, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer I have so far is:
https://github.com/chitika/cberl

This project is based on the C++ "official" couchbase client.

It seems to have two possible problems:

1) it might be abandoned (last activity was 3 months ago) 
2) it uses an NIF, which as I understand it, cannot be accessed concurrently.

Comment: I am the maintainer of cberl. You can find a more recent ( and broken :)) version on https://github.com/aliyakamercan/cberl/. The make file is broken and it cannot be  build. I will fix it during this week or the next. You can not access it concurrently, but you can create a pool of connection with poolboy or something similar. During my tests one instance was able to handle ~1.5k operations per second on a vm.

Comment: If you would make an answer to the question, and flesh it out a little bit, you'll probably earn the bounty.  (I can't award the bounty to a comment.)

Poolboy would create a pool of connections.  My various clients could pull connections off of that pool and then talk to cberl thru them-- but that would be accessing it concurrently.  When you say that you "can not access concurrently" it sounds like I need the opposite of a pool-- a single process that talks to CBERL and multiplexes the accesses from a variety of client processes (which seems consistent with how libcouchbase works I think.)

Comment: I updated cberl to compile with the latest version of libcouchbase.  https://github.com/xcrdev/cberl

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: yes, Couchbase is compatible with memcached text protocol.

But the key point here is "memcached text protocol". Since memcached is using two different protocol types (text and binary), you should use those clients that are using text protocol.

At Mochi, we are using merle for memcached, and looks like it should work for you. Recently, one of my colleagues forked it and made some minor corrections: https://github.com/twonds/merle

Also, consider taking a look at https://github.com/EchoTeam/mcd. This client could use some refactoring, but is also production proven and even allows simple sharding.

Comment: I understand the binary protocol is much more efficient.  My question is about the binary protocol.  The package I linked do: erlmc says it speaks "Binary protocol" and "protocol 1.3", yet your response is about the text protocol and implies I should use the text protocol.

Comment: Binary protocol is more efficient, but not that much: text protocol of memcached is very simple, and just slightly less compact than binary one.

Comment: And, frankly, I don't know if Membase supports binary protocol, but at the first glance – it doesn't. The easiest way to figure it out is to test some binary protocol client on memcached first and then try it on Membase.

Comment: The question isn't about membase, but couchbase 2.0, which does use the binary protocol.  I'm looking for a binary protocol client in erlang, that's the point of the question.

Comment: That is the very project that I was asking about in the question, referenced in the very first two sentences of the question.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't hyperlink-highlighted, slipped of my sight

Comment: BTW, turns out that any access to Couchbase via SASL or a dedicated port (eg: assign a port to your bucket) will go thru the built-in MOXI, which speaks either text based or binary protocol.  So my fretting was for naught.  At the time I asked the original question I was operating under several misapprehensions and not much info.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Xavier's contributions, I refactored the whole thing added pooling, now it builds and performs okay. I also included a basho_bench driver so you can benchmark it yourself. You can find the code on [here](https://github.com/aliyakamercan/cberl) . I am pretty sure this would perform better than text protocol.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't give you the bounty (your answer came after the deadline when I had to assign it, and I couldn't give it to your comment below....) I've upvoted your answers to other questions in compensation.  Thanks for your work on cberl, I'm gonna pull it and start trying to use it today.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create own vbucket aware erlmc based erlang couchbase client.
The differences:
- http connection to retrieve vbucket map from couchbase
- fill two "reserved" bytes with vbucket id (see python client for example)
- active once async tcp connection for performance reason

Comment: I'm assuming this client is not open source, since you didn't give a link to it?    Is there a way to have the couchbase 2.0 server handle the distribution, so the client doesn't have to be so smart?

Answer (score 1):

We don't use Couchbase with Erlang, but with Python, which also needs to connect with a memcache client.  I can't speak to the Erlang libraries specifically, but hopefully the lessons apply in both situations.

**Memcache Client Limitations**

Memcache clients can only access memcache functionality.  You won't be able to use views or any other features not specified in the memcache protocol.  If you want access to the views, you will need to use the REST protocol separately on port 8092 ([docs](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-querying-rest-api.html)).

**Connecting to Couchbase with Vanilla Memcache Clients**

The ports mentioned on that page are used either internally or by "smart" clients written for Couchbase specifically.  By default, memcache clients can connect to the normal memcache port 11211 on any of the nodes in your Couchbase cluster.  Do not use the memcache cluster features of any memcache client not written specifically for Couchbase; the usual methods of distribution for vanilla memcached are incompatible with Couchbase.

**Explanation**

In order to connect with the memcached client, you need to connect to port for the Couchbase bucket directly.  When you set up a new bucket, you specify the port you want the bucket to be accessible on.  The default bucket is setup on port 11211.  Each bucket acts like an independent memcached instance, but is internally distributed to all nodes in the cluster.  You can connect to the bucket port on any of the Couchbase servers, and you will be accessing the same data set.

This means that you should not try to use the distributed memcache features of your memcache client.  Those features are designed for ad-hoc memcached clusters.  Just connect to the appropriate port on the Couchbase server as if it was a single memcached server.

The reason this is possible is because there is a Moxi instance which finds the appropriate Couchbase server to process the request.  This Moxi instance automatically runs for each bucket on every Couchbase server. Even though you may not be connected to the node which has your specific key, Moxi will transparently direct your request to the appropriate server.

In this way, you can use a vanilla Memcache client to talk to Couchbase, without needing any additional logic to keep track of cluster topology.  Moxi takes care of that piece for you.

**Binary protocol**

We did have the binary protocol working at one point, but there were problems when we tried to use the `flush_all` command.  That was a while ago, though.  I suggest experimenting yourself to see if the level of support meets your needs.

Comment: The flush_all operation has been disabled by default to prevent accidental flush operations affecting the data stored in a bucket. You can enable flush_all by setting the parameter using the cbflushctl command:

shell> /opt/couchbase/bin/cbflushctl localhost:11210 set flushall_enabled true
setting flush param: flushall_enabled true